# using java default binarysearch on biginteger

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger, binary-search

I have used the [binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) on array of `BigInteger`, I tested with a few numbers, seems working fine. So I assume I don't need to implement/override any methods (e.g. Comparator) for it to work properly?

I'm using the following method:

```
static int  binarySearch(Object[] a, Object key) 
//Searches the specified array for the specified object using the binary search algorithm.
```

Like this:

```
int i = Arrays.binarySearch(arrayOfBigIntsPreDefined,new BigInteger("1111111111111111"));
```

If there is a better/proper/well-known method, please also suggest.

Comment: So let me get this right. It works for you. There is no performance problem. Why did you ask this question again?

Comment: @AdamGent She was asking for confirmation of this approach and other potentially better ones.

Comment: @javadba I wasn't trying to be snarky about it its just that I don't know what to assume. For example I assume the OP knows the array has to be sorted. Do I need to explain that as well? However I now realize based on the other answer the OP just didn't know that BigInteger is a comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigInteger` already implements `Comparable<BigInteger>`, so there's no need to pass in your own `Comparator` (unless you for some reason decide to redefine how two `BigInteger` are compared).